# Norm of the inner product on an inner product space when considered as a continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space equipped with the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Fix some arbitrary $y \in V$ and define the map $f_y: V \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$f_y(x) = \langle x,y \rangle, \qquad x \in V.$$
A few questions on MSE have shown that $f_y$ is a continuous linear functional with respect to the standard norm on V $\lVert x \rVert_V = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$, for example by showing that $f_y \in B(V,\mathbb{C})$ (the space of bounded linear functionals from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$).

**I want to show that the norm of $f_y$ in $B(V, \mathbb{C})$ equals $\lVert y \rVert_V$.**

By the Cauchy-Shwarz inequality we have that $\lvert f_y(x) \rvert = \lvert \langle x,y \rangle \rvert \leq \lVert x \rVert_V \lVert y \rVert_V$, so $f_y$ is bounded and hence continuous. I suspect that I can use this result to find an upper and lower bound for $\lVert f_y \rVert$ that are equal (in other words showing that $\lVert f_y \rVert \leq K$ and $\lVert f_y \rVert \geq K$, for $K = \lVert y \rVert_V$), but am not sure on how to proceed along this line of reasoning. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $|f_y(y)| = ||y||_V^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already shown that $\|f_y\|≤\|y\|$. And you also have
$$
\|y\|^2=\langle y,y\rangle =f_y(y)\leq\|f_y\|\,\|y\|.
$$
Since $y\ne0$ (as the case $y=0$ can be trivially be treated separately), you get $\|f_y\|≥\|y\|$.